# fix errors according to npm install

Tags: vue.js, npm

I tried to npm install with vuejs and i stuck with this error

anyone help me

npm ERR! code E400
npm ERR! 400 Bad URI - GET http://registry.npmjs.org/http-proxy-middleware/-/http-proxy-middleware-0.19.1.tgz

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users..\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2022-03-17T06_55_12_771Z-debug-0.log

Comment: You should check [https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/18243#issuecomment-325218531](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/18243#issuecomment-325218531)

Comment: does not work for me @fatm